# Функция (Проверка на пустоту)

Tags: javascript

Начинающий в js прошу сильно не пинать)
функция по клику создает заголовок h4, так же вместе с заголовком создается ссылка с кнопкой удаления заголовка....
в общем, если поле ввода пустое, и мы нажимаем добавить, то естественно заголовок не добавляется а вот ссылка с пустым дивом тут как тут))) Как прописать условие так что бы при клике происходила проверка!

```
function QuizHead(e) {
console.log('click');
if(quizInput.value === '') {
    alert('Добавьте заголовок');
}else {
    // Create h4 element
    var h4 = document.createElement('h4');
    // Add class
    h4.className = 'CreateTest';
    // Create text node and append to li
    h4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(quizInput.value));
    //Создаем ссылку (кнопку) удаление поля
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    //Добавляем class ссылке
    link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
    //Добавляем иконку в html
    link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';
    // Append the link to li
    h4.appendChild(link);

    // Append h4 to new div
    quizList.appendChild(h4);
}
```

Comment: Решил сам! добавляем return после alert('Добавьте заголовок');

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях при проверке ещё вызывают trim() дабы исключить ввод пробелов вместо текста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function quizHead(e) {
  console.log("click");
  let value = quizInput.value.trim();
  if (value.length) {
    let h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    h4.className = "create-test";
    h4.textContent = value;
    link.className = "delete-item secondary-content";
    link.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-remove'></i>";
    h4.appendChild(link);
    quizList.appendChild(h4);
  } else {
    alert("Добавьте заголовок");
  }    
}
```